# Build URL Using Multi-Dimensional Array where Category & Sub-Category Have The Same Name

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array combined with Category & Sub-Category properties that are unfortunately using the same names *(not my design but see below)* for both Category/Sub-Category where:

- `[udf] => 2` signifies all *Categories*
- `[udf] => 3` denotes all *Sub-Categories*

I need to create a `foreach` loop that builds URLs containing URL parameters for both the Category and Sub-Category

**Example Output:**

- `<a href="https://example.com/?category=21&subcategory=24"> Red </a>`
- `<a href="https://example.com/?category=22&subcategory=25"> Orange </a>`
- `<a href="https://example.com/?category=23&subcategory=26"> Blue </a>`

In the example above I'm building a URL that links parameters to all `Red`,`Organge`, and `Blue` related Categories and Sub-Categories. The parameters should be correctly placed using the `udf` key/value pair where any *key* with a *value* of `2` is a category and any `udf` key with a value of `3` is a sub-category. On top of that, I also need to grab the correct value of `name` property to use in the URL.

**Example Array:**

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 21
                [name] => Red
                [udf] => 2
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 22
                [name] => Orange
                [udf] => 2
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 23
                [name] => Blue
                [udf] => 2
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 24
                [name] => Red
                [udf] => 3
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [id] => 25
                [name] => Orange
                [udf] => 3
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [id] => 26
                [name] => Blue
                [udf] => 3
            )
    )
```

Comment: what is the total number of categories and sub categories ?

Comment: is the number of category and subcategory is same ?
and do they always exists in the same array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following approach:

```
// sample array
$arr= [
    ['id' => 21, 'name' => "Red", 'udf' => 2], 
    ['id' => 22, 'name' => "Orange", 'udf' => 2],
    ['id' => 23, 'name' => "Red", 'udf' => 3], 
    ['id' => 24, 'name' => "Orange", 'udf' => 3],
];

$result = [];
foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
    $result[$v['name']][ ($v['udf'] == 2)? 'cat':'subcat' ] = $v['id'];
}

// outputting urls
foreach($result as $k => $v) {
    echo "<a href='https://example.com/?category={$v['cat']}"
          . "&subcategory={$v['subcat']}'>$k</a>" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

The output:

```
<a href='https://example.com/?category=21&subcategory=23'>Red</a>
<a href='https://example.com/?category=22&subcategory=24'>Orange</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array consists same number of category and subcategory then the following solution may serve the purpose

```
<?php
 $array = array
    (
        array
            (
                'id' => 21,
                'name' => 'Red',
                'udf' => 2
            ),
        array
            (
                'id' => 22,
                'name' => 'Orange',
                'udf' => 2
            ),
        array
            (
                'id' => 23,
                'name' => 'Blue',
                'udf' => 2
            ),
        array
            (
                'id' => 24,
                'name' => 'Red',
                'udf' => 3
            ),
        array
            (
                'id' => 25,
                'name' => 'Orange',
                'udf' => 3
            ),
        array
            (
                'id' => 26,
                'name' => 'Blue',
                'udf' => 3
            )
    );
    $l = count($array)/2 ;
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php for($i = 0; $i < $l; $i++): ?>
    <li>
        <a href="https://example.com/?category=<?= $array[$i]['id'] ?>&subcategory=<?= $array[$i+3]['id'] ?>">
            <?= $array[$i]['name'] ?>
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The output : 
    http://main.xfiddle.com/52d90fa6/sifat.php

for the better view of code please click [here](https://ideone.com/HnzsSi)